# Django - Unable to retrieve data in database in dropdownlist

Tags: python, mysql, django

**Hi, I really need help in this, tried for many days and still cannot do it. I am very new to Django.**

*Problem:* I am unable to retrieve the data in MySQL database to display it in a drop-down list. Can someone help me, please? Much appreciated!

*models.py*

```
class paper(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(max_length=70, primary_key=True, null=False)
year = models.TextField(null=True)
month = models.TextField(null=True)
number = models.IntegerField(null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

*Views.py*

```
def dropdown_list(request):
paper = paper.objects.all()
pname = request.GET.get('paper_id')
context = {
    "paper": paper,
    "name": pname
}
return render(request, 'exampapersNew/exampaper.html', context)
```

*exampaper.html*

```
        <form id="form1" method="GET">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <u>SELECT YEAR</u><br><br>
      <select>
        {% if paper %}
        {% for p in paper %}
            <option value="{{ p.id }}">{{ p.year }} {{ p.month }} Paper {{ p.number }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      </select>
    </form>
```

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^feedback/', include('feedback.urls')),
  url(r'^exampapersNew/', include('exampapersNew.urls')),
  url(r'^$', views.HomeView, name = 'home'),
  url(r'^feedback', views.FeedbackM, name = 'feedback'),
  url(r'^exampapersNew', views.ExampapersNewView, name = 'exampapersNew'),
  url(r'^frequentlyasked', views.FrequentlyaskedView, name = 'frequentlyasked'),
  url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),

  url(r'^exampapersNew/<int:paper_id>/', views.EMaths_Menu, name = 'paper_archive'),
  url(r'^formula', views.e_math_concept, name = 'formula'),
]
```

forms.py

```
class DropdownForm(forms.Form):
class Meta:
    model = paper
    fields = ['id', 'year', 'month', 'number']
```

mySQL Table

```
mysql> SELECT * from exampapersnew_paper;
+-----------+------+----------+--------+
| id        | year | month    | number |
+-----------+------+----------+--------+
| 200801001 | 2008 | November |      1 |
| 200801002 | 2008 | November |      2 |
| 200901001 | 2009 | November |      1 |
+-----------+------+----------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: you are not passing the variable **`z`** to the template through **`context`**

Comment: return render(request, 'exampapersNew/exampaper.html', {"paperS": paperS})

Comment: @JPG is there any other ways I could do this?

Comment: @eddwinpaz tried this but still couldn’t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, in your select

```
{% if paper %}
{% for p in paper %}
    <option value="{{ p.id }}">{{ p.year }} {{ p.month }} Paper {{ p.number }} </option>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Also go through this tutorial, [django tutorial part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/).

Also django models have a default primary key attribute you can use that also.

Comment: Still not displaying T.T... I really don’t know what’s wrong

Comment: @Gerry it would be request.GET.get('paper_id') and maybe set context as context = {"paper": obj_list, "name": pname} and send context only to your template as render(request, 'exampapersNew/exampaper.html', context)

Comment: changed as edited, in the select list it’s still not displaying

Comment: I tried this and it worked for me, try clearing your cache and try using {% debug %} in your html to see what contents are in your paper.

Comment: I did install tastypie api in my app earlier, I’m not sure if this is the cause of it?

Comment: Are you getting a select option with no contents in it or is there an error rendering the HTML page, have you added some rows in your paper table or is it empty

Comment: i am getting a select option with no contents in it, yes i have added some rows in my paper table.

Comment: Ok, I have made a small project in github repository maybe that will help, [github link](https://github.com/Tecvoc/DjangoTemp).

Comment: i tried to run yours but also shows a select list with no option in it..

Comment: Can you try now, I tested on someone else's computer also and it is working

Comment: same still, i really dont know why. is there something wrong with my software?

Answer (score 0):

The render function requires some context to be passed. You are only denoting the place where it would be rendered, not the context.
Example:

```
def product_list(request):
    category = Category.objects.all()
     context = {
               'category': category,
    }
    return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', context)
```

Notice here the categories are rendered in list.html because context it passed through the render function.

Comment: I tried this method as well, nothing is being displayed

Comment: can you show your forms.py is the Meta name paperS?

Comment: where did you paperS come from?

Comment: change paperS to paper

Comment: Is it paper instead? I thought the paperS is another variable that needs to be declared

Comment: it has to be the same name declared in meta in forms.py

Comment: Can anyone help please

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's best to name your classes with capital letter (`class Paper(models.model)`)

Second, I think your url should be like
 `url(r'^exampapersNew/?paper_id=<int:paper_id>/', views.EMaths_Menu)`
*question mark in front of paper_id* in order to get paper_id with request.GET.get('paper_id')

I am trying to do my best to help you but without all the code, I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please push your code to github and let me know.